# как правильно оформляется слоган?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие, реклама

пишу индивидуальный проект по русскому языку, мне предложили тему «телевизионная реклама». она заключается в том, чтобы найти какие-либо ошибки или интересные моменты в рекламах.
скажите, может ли слоган компании писаться через двоеточие? Например: *«Литрес: я так читаю»*.
Как вообще пишутся слоганы? Через тире, точку, двоеточие? Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны различные варианты по контексту, например:

(1) ***Литрес** — я так читаю.*

Пауза обозначена тире. Присоединительное значение. Это более вероятное решение.

(2) ***Литрес:** я так читаю.*

Пауза больше, пояснительное значение.

Выбор делается с учетом семантики и интонации. Здесь **бессоюзная связь**, которую можно обозначить различными способами, что разрешено **правилами.**

Нужно видеть слоган, тогда можно определить правильность постановки в нем знаков.